# Favicon not showing

Tags: favicon

My favicon is showing when accessing the website, but it's not showing when searching it on Google. The website is https://discovernavarra.com. I have tried several things like clearing my browser cache, making sure it follows the Google guidelines (it is 144x144 px). Also inserting the following link in the header:

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://discovernavarra.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/Flavicon_new.png" type="image/png"/>
```

But nothing seems to work. Do you have any more tips?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the favicon named `Flavicon_new.png`? Maybe `Favicon_new.png`?

Comment: You may have to wait for Google to crawl your site, especially if this is a recent addition to your site.

Comment: the file loads ok, this is probably unrelated to WordPress and more of a google crawler question